# How can I find out if my laptop has bluetooth support?

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad

In my Lubuntu 18.04 on Thinkpad T400,  how can I find out if my laptop has bluetooth support? The bluetooth icon on the panel in the desktop says "No Bluetooth Adapter found". Does it mean that my laptop doesn't have bluetooth support?

If the laptop itself has bluetooth support, how can I enable it and use it with a wireless headphone in Lubuntu?

[image]

Comment: See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or the two Lubuntu forum posts  (Lubuntu's last release announcement can be read at https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ which states it was supported until April-2021)

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or the latest UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie (*my first comment was the wrong paste sorry & related to 16.04*)

Comment: You can consult the documentation for the model of your laptop. This will tell you whether or not the device has a Bluetooth adapter and if so, it should also tell you the manufacturer and model number of the adapter you have. Then you can use the model number of your Bluetooth adapter as a search term here on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can check kernel modules because it would have picked it up and loaded it on start-up. From the command line execute this:

```
    dmesg | grep -i blue
```

If something like this returned, your laptop has Bluetooth capability:

```
    [    2.933062] usb 1-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
```