# My system has bluetooth in built but ubuntu is not giving option to turn it on

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, sound, bluetooth

I have a Hp 15 laptop which has Bluetooth in built but ubuntu is not recognizing the Bluetooth. In Bluetooth option in settings it says `No Bluetooth Found. Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth`.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304427/install-bluetooth-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04) process to install Bluetooth drivers but it don't help me.

I also tried this [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336375/how-can-i-find-out-if-my-laptop-has-bluetooth-support) to find out if my laptop has Bluetooth or not and it gives me this output which I think my laptop has Bluetooth.

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[  311.122671] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  311.122714] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[  311.122716] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  311.122722] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  311.122725] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  311.122731] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  318.041294] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  318.041298] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  318.041303] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue? I need to use Bluetooth earbuds with my laptop.

I have also run the command suggest by @Pilot6 in comments and here's the output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:03d2 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Show the output of `rfkill`

Comment: @RishonJR
```
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked

```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the above of the command